# Maven: How to protect a Java 7 project from using jar artifacts that compile against Java 8?

Tags: java, maven, java-8, maven-3, java-7

I have a project that is run by customers using a Java 7 runtime.

I added a dependency in an artifact that compiles against Java 8 - uses Java 8 features, like lambdas and streams.

When compiling my project, I don't get any error that something is wrong.

In runtime though, I get a bunch of error, not recognizing stuff, obviously.

**Is there a way to protect my project from using artifact depending on higher level Java?** Thanks.

* This is a general question for an artifact depending on some low level Java API that tries to add a dependency on another artifact that depends on higher level Java.

* I guess this is because Java is not part of the explicit dependency definition but rather implicit. The question is how to make it more explicit and protected.

Comment: I don't think that there is a general solution. What I can think of is to fix your dependency definition in your POM to the last known working version. Did you configure your POM to use a real Java7 compiler installed on your PC to compile your project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [maven-enforcer-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) in combination with the [extra-enforcer-rule](http://www.mojohaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/enforceBytecodeVersion.html) which looks like this:

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-bytecode-version</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <enforceBytecodeVersion>
                  <maxJdkVersion>1.7</maxJdkVersion>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>org.mindrot:jbcrypt</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </enforceBytecodeVersion>
              </rules>
              <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>extra-enforcer-rules</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-6</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

You can make it more safe to use another [enforcer-rule](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireJavaVersion.html) which you can use to force to use the correct JDK

Comment: Why the `org.mindrot:jbcrypt` exclusion?

Comment: Just as an example...